# Showing that the set of linear mappings from a finite-dimensional vector space to an infinite-dimensional vector space is infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the exercise 12 from chapter 3.A of *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler. I'm asking for hints on how to finish the proof, and how to make the "proof" more rigid.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathrm{F}$ with $\mathrm{dim}(V) > 0$, and suppose that $W$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over the (same) field $\mathrm{F}$. We have to show that $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is infinite-dimensional. Consider the projection mappings $\mathrm{pr}_i(x) = \mathrm{pr}_i\left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \alpha_i v_i\right) = \alpha_1 w_i$, where $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are the basis vectors of $V$, $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in \mathrm{F}$ and $w_k, k \in \mathrm{N}$ are the basis vectors of $W$. Evidently all $\mathrm{pr}_i, i \in \mathrm{N}$, are linear and as $\mathrm{pr}_i(1) = w_i$, $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ contains all basis vectors of $W$. Hence $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ contains an infinite list of linearly independent vectors.

And this is where my mind goes blank. Namely at this point in the book there hasn't really been any discussion about the "component-wise" representation of linear-mappings, just general properties that hold for them.

Comment: What do you mean by "component-wise". I don't see such a thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\operatorname{pr}_i$ are indeed linearly independent. Let $I\subset\mathbb N$ be a finite set of integers and assume that
$$
\sum_{i\in I}a_i\operatorname{pr}_i = 0,
$$
where the $a_i$ are numbers in $F$. Plugging $v_1$ into this gives
$$
0 = \sum_{i\in I}a_i\operatorname{pr}_i(v_1) = \sum_{i\in I}a_iw_i.
$$
But since the $w_i$ are linearly independent, it follows that $a_i=0$ for all $i\in I$.

Comment: So that as any finite set of of vectors $w_1,\dots,w_k$ are l.i., it follows that the basis is infinite?

Comment: We know that the basis $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots\}$ of $W$ is infinite. And this implies an infinite basis of $L(V,W)$, namely $\{\operatorname{pr}_1,\operatorname{pr}_2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Ah I see. I had forgotten what the technical requirement for a vector space to be infinite-dimenisonal was. Namely, a v.s. is infinite-dimenisional only if there exists a sequence of vectors $\{v_n\}$ such that the list formed by the sequence is linearly independent for every possible choice of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.